# Using foreach Loop In PHP To Parse Json

Tags: php, json, parsing

I'm using iTunes RSS generator to get HOT tracks, now I'm using following way to parse JSON:

```
<?php
$json_string = 'https://rss.itunes.apple.com/api/v1/in/apple-music/hot-tracks/all/10/explicit.json';
$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
$cltn = $obj['feed']['results'][0]['collectionName'];
echo $cltn;
?>
```

Now, as we know that It'll return only 1 collectionName.
JSON request is returning 10 results. How can I get them all using foreach loop? I've used several ways but no success.

Comment: Post the array as a var_export. It's hard to answer when we don't see the array.

Comment: Just iterate over $obj[feed][results]

Comment: @Andreas To see the array, just go to the provided url https://rss.itunes.apple.com/api/v1/in/apple-music/hot-tracks/all/10/explicit.json

Comment: @FrédéricClausset That is impossible to read on a mobile. Also MVCE means the data should be contained inside the question, not in links that may fail and make the question useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't give the output of the array I assume the [0] index is what needs to be iterated.

You need to foreach the `$obj['feed']['results']` by doing:

```
Foreach($obj['feed']['results'] as $cltn){
    Echo $cltn['collectionName'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's what i wanted :) You saved my time :)

Comment: But please don't use `Echo`, use `echo` and `foreach` respectively X.X

Comment: @Dan that makes no difference. It's purely esthetic. Just like placing the `{` inline or below a function. But I will also say that it's because I type in a mobile that the autocorrect does that for me.

Comment: @Andreas while syntactically it makes no difference, it is non-standard and makes it harder for other developers to work with your code. Also the PHP tokeniser is tuned to expect lowercase keywords, your use of uppercase could have a performance impact in some scenarios.

Comment: @Geoffrey it can have some impact sure. But it seems to be inconsistent when I run the code. Sometimes on some versions it's actually faster to write with first letter capitalized. https://3v4l.org/vKJ4v

Comment: @Andreas your test is faulty, a loop will not show a performance difference because PHP compiles your code into intermediate opcodes. Any differences you see here are due to the varied load of the server you are running this test on. The parsing happens once at startup, and then PHP runs the opcodes, it is this initial parsing that will suffer.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this way with [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to iterate your array in `key=>value` manner as you've decoded the json as an `array` not an `object` in php.

```
<?php
$json_string = 'https://rss.itunes.apple.com/api/v1/in/apple-music/hot-tracks/all/10/explicit.json';
$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$array = json_decode($jsondata,true);
# printing resulted array just for debugging purpose
print '<pre>';
print_r($array);
print '</pre>';
foreach($array['feed']['results'] as $key=>$value){
    echo $value['collectionName'].'<br/>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: @Sachin https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . by the way I was first person to give you the answer :)

Comment: @BeingSunny it's not about who was first. But if you want to know I had my answer ready to post at the same time as I posted the comment to the question asking for the output of the array. But since I had to go and couldn't wait for the answer, I posted a guess answer. Yes you may have pushed the button first but my answer was completed earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Foreach over the results:

```
foreach ($obj['feed']['results'] as $result) {
    echo $result['collectionName'] . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided you can iterate the results to get all possible information from the artist/track list, for example:

```
$json_string = 'https://rss.itunes.apple.com/api/v1/in/apple-music/hot-tracks/all/10/explicit.json';
$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
$cltn = $obj['feed']['results'];

function test_print($item, $key)
{
    echo "<strong>".$key."</strong>: ".$item."<br>";
}

foreach($cltn as $key => $c) {
    echo "Result No ".($key+1)."<br>";
    array_walk_recursive($c, 'test_print');
}
```

in case you only want to show `artistName` and `collectionName` you can slightly modify the above example:

```
$json_string = 'https://rss.itunes.apple.com/api/v1/in/apple-music/hot-tracks/all/10/explicit.json';
$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
$cltn = $obj['feed']['results'];

foreach($cltn as $c) {
       echo $c['artistName'].": ".$c['collectionName']."<br>";
}
```

You can try all the above in [PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/)